# Recursive download of subfolder with wget - --no-parent apparently not working

Tags: download, wget, recursive

I need some documentation about XUL but I do not have Internet access most of the time. So, I've tried to download [the Mozilla Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial) with the following command:

```
wget --no-parent -r -l 2 -p -k https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial
```

My intention was to download both the `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial` page and its subpages (for example, `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Install_Scripts`). However, even though I passed the `--no-parent` flag, it keeps getting pages such as `https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=Special:Userlogin&returntotitle=en%2FXUL+Tutorial%2FInstall+Scripts`.

I do not understand why it happens. How could I achieve the behavior I intended?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need the trailing slash at the end of the URL.

Comment: I tried `wget --no-parent -r -l 2 -p -k https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/` but it only download the `index.html` file...

Comment: that was my issue! probably common among wget beginners

Comment: `it only download the index.html file` That was because you were using `l 2`. Since you did not change the accepted answer, I guess you never increased the recursion level to realize this is the best answer for the question as it had been asked.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Confirmed.

Comment: I can also confirm. I spent about 1h trying different combinations of flags, and navigating the internet. So frustrating that it all boiled down to a simple missing slash. I wonder how wget interprets the command without the slash.

Answer (score 2):

Was having a similar issue:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -nH "https://www.website.com/parent/directory/"
```

I believe there was an issue with `https` vs. `http`. I updated `$HOME/.wgetrc` to:

```
header = Accept-Encoding: none
header = Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
header = Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
header = Connection: keep-alive
user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
referer = http://www.google.com/
robots = off
```

Then changed changed `https` to `http`:

```
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -nH "http://www.website.com/parent/directory/"
```

The `wget` program no longer created folders (or retrieved files) from outside the specified directory hierarchy.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to work perfectly. Waiting the end of the download (which I do not need anymore actually) to be sure :) However, I did not changed to HTTP - I mean, I changed, but it kept redirecting to HTTPS. Do you know why your `.wgetrc` seems to be changing the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable gzip compression to make it work. I also changed the user-agent because some pages forbid wget. So this is what I've put into my .wgetrc:

> header = Accept-Encoding: none
>
> user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US;
>   rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6

Works great here.

Comment: The solution is the other answer: the trailing slash at the end of the URL is needed.